# ngrok direct link is not working on camphish?

Tags: kali-linux

I'm trying to use Camphish in my Kali linux and for generating "Direct link" it uses `ngrok` or `servo` server but in my system I tried both, but it is still not generating direct link.

**Error:** *As you can see in below picture `ngrok` doesn't show any link*

**Note**: I already download `ngrok` from it's official site and set its token but it also does not work for me.

**Tool I'm using :** [Camphish](https://github.com/techchipnet/CamPhish)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code has some problem in printing the ip or link but i found a solution.
ngrok opens the tunnel at port 3333 so direct go there.

1. Go that that camphish folder
2. open terminal in that folder
3. ./ngrok http 3333
4. wait
5. the link will come in http and https like this https://9775-106-206-39-59.ngrok.io
6. your link will be different but paste it in your browser and that will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you bro it's working now!!

Comment: bash ./camphish.sh and then do all that